# run a method in start up

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I wanted to run an async method in asp.net core stat up file but it make an error
here it is the my code:
 `initialRoles(roleManager, userManager).Wait();`

and method is :

```
private async Task initialRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            IdentityRole identityRole = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("admin");
            if (identityRole == null)
            {
                identityRole = new IdentityRole("admin");
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(identityRole);
            }
         }
```

and error is :"An error occurred while updating the entries"

Comment: You should check the innerexception and it's message and share it here.... You might already have `admin` role in the database and error may be because you are trying to create duplicate role...but that's just a guess... without seeing actual error message it is hard to suggest any solution

Comment: You may want to show the surrounding code. `.Wait()` should be avoided and shouldn't be necessary. And how did you get the instances for roleManager and userManager?

Answer (score 1):

You can create role by writing below code. In your code, you are passing role name in IdentityRole object.

```
 var role = new IdentityRole();
 role.Name = "admin";
 await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
```

Pls upvote if it helps.